# .NET Regex: Splitting logs with multiline entries

Tags: .net, regex

I want to parse a log file that looks like this, capturing the date and message from each log entry:

```
[12/18/2017 1:22:12 PM] LOG FILE STREAM STARTED - v2.1.6561.24062, BUILD 12/18/2017 1:22:04 PM
[12/18/2017 1:22:17 PM]  Network Configuration Changed: Current status of all interfaces:
 - Ethernet 2 is DOWN - self-assigned IP
[12/18/2017 1:22:29 PM]  Network Configuration Changed: Current status of all interfaces:
 - Ethernet 2  is UP - IP address = 172.16.10.191
```

If each entry were a single line, this would work quite easily with `^(\[.+\])\s+(.*)`.  However, certain entries span multiple lines -- for example, for the `1:22:17 PM` entry I'd like to capture all of

```
Network Configuration Changed: Current status of all interfaces:
 - Ethernet 2 is DOWN - self-assigned IP
```

as the message.

How can I make the second capturing group continue across line boundaries until the next match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

This answer allows for `[` and `]` to be present in the log information string (so long as it's not the first character in the line).

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5C%5B%28%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D*%29%5C%5D%28%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%3F%28%3F%3D%5E%5C%5B%7C%5Cz%29%29&i=%5B12%2F18%2F2017%201%3A22%3A12%20PM%5D%20LOG%20FILE%20STREAM%20STARTED%20-%20v2.1.6561.24062%2C%20BUILD%2012%2F18%2F2017%201%3A22%3A04%20PM%0D%0A%5B12%2F18%2F2017%201%3A22%3A17%20PM%5D%20%20Network%20Configuration%20Changed%3A%20Current%20%5Bstatus%5D%20of%20all%20interfaces%3A%0D%0A%20-%20Ethernet%202%20is%20DOWN%20-%20self-assigned%20IP%0D%0A%5B12%2F18%2F2017%201%3A22%3A29%20PM%5D%20%20Network%20Configuration%20Changed%3A%20Current%20status%20of%20all%20interfaces%3A%0D%0A%20-%20Ethernet%202%20%20is%20UP%20-%20IP%20address%20%3D%20172.16.10.191&o=m)

```
^\[([^\]]*)\]([\s\S]*?(?=^\[|\z))
```

**Note**: The above regex uses the `Multiline` flag.

Optionally, you can also use [`^\[(\[^\]\]*)\](.*?(?=^\[|\z))` with the addition of another flag `Singleline`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5C%5B%28%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D*%29%5C%5D%28.*%3F%28%3F%3D%5E%5C%5B%7C%5Cz%29%29&i=%5B12%2F18%2F2017%201%3A22%3A12%20PM%5D%20LOG%20FILE%20STREAM%20STARTED%20-%20v2.1.6561.24062%2C%20BUILD%2012%2F18%2F2017%201%3A22%3A04%20PM%0D%0A%5B12%2F18%2F2017%201%3A22%3A17%20PM%5D%20%20Network%20Configuration%20Changed%3A%20Current%20%5Bstatus%5D%20of%20all%20interfaces%3A%0D%0A%20-%20Ethernet%202%20is%20DOWN%20-%20self-assigned%20IP%0D%0A%5B12%2F18%2F2017%201%3A22%3A29%20PM%5D%20%20Network%20Configuration%20Changed%3A%20Current%20status%20of%20all%20interfaces%3A%0D%0A%20-%20Ethernet%202%20%20is%20UP%20-%20IP%20address%20%3D%20172.16.10.191&o=sm)

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `\[` Match a the left square bracket `[` literally
- `([^\]]*)` Capture any character except `]` any number of times into capture group 1
- `\]` Match the right square bracket `]` literally
- `([\s\S]*?(?=^\[|\z))` Capture the following into capture group 2

  - `[\s\S]*?` Match any character any number of times (but as few as possible)
  - `(?=^\[|\z)` Positive lookahead ensuring either of the following match

    - `^\[` Matches `[` (literally) at the start of a new line
    - `\z` Assert position at the absolute end of the string

Answer (score 0):

He's one I tested with your given text: `(\[.+\])\s+([^[]+)`. The second group will match any character that isn't a `[` at least 1 time and since your logs always begin with a `[` it gives the wanted result.

Regex101 example: https://regex101.com/r/Bzg3xp/1/

Comment: I will be happy to get an explanation for the -1 :)

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but mind explaining what it does?  Looks like the second capturing group is matching everything that's not an open-bracket? I'm surprised you don't have to escape the open bracket!

Comment: I added an explanation, and I don't believe you need to escape characters when using `[^..]` (as seen in the regex101 example).

Comment: Ok - while that technically works, I want a more robust solution.  This obviously fails if there are any bracket chars in the log message itself. Is there a way to say "match everything up until a newline and open bracket"?

Comment: How would you then difference a breacket char in the log message and the bracket in the time? Unless you make your first group more strict